# Get specific section of XML from corrupted XML file

Tags: php, xml, substring

I have an XML file that I fetch from an external server(via curl), but for some reason it's corrupted and SimpleXML goes crazy and shoots errors everytime i try to parse it, even if it's in a string. So, I decided I might try to get the specific part of the XML file i need:

```
<codes>
    <code1code>There is no Code available.</code1code>
    <code2text>Please try again later.</code2text>
</codes>
```

How can I do this? I've tried substr, preg_match, str_replace, and I've searched everywhere but none of the solutions work! please help me out, thanks!

Comment: Hmm, maybe look at the corruption first - HTML parsing mode would be more lenient but likely to make trouble with unknown tags. Can you show how the XML file is corrupted exactly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yoy mean something like that

```
$info = <<<text
<test>
<codes>
        <code1code>There is no Code available.</code1code>
        <code2text>Please try again later.</code2text>
    </codes>
text;


    $xml = new SimpleXMLElement ($info, LIBXML_NOERROR|LIBXML_ERR_NONE|LIBXML_ERR_FATAL);
```

Notice that `test` tag is not closed, but any errors are suppresed.

```
object(SimpleXMLElement)#1 (1) {
  ["codes"]=>
  object(SimpleXMLElement)#2 (2) {
    ["code1code"]=>
    string(27) "There is no Code available."
    ["code2text"]=>
    string(23) "Please try again later."
  }
}
```

Comment: Will this work, though? Will you get a workable XML structure from it?

Comment: Fixes my corruption error, thanks! However, i discovered that using SimpleXML also helped me out. - Although, is there any way to delete questions that are dumb? Its unfortunate that this happened.